# preg_replace arabic title like مرحبا-اهلاً-بك-هنا

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

guys i have tried a lot of function but no one of them help me the way that supposed to be.

i have htaccess to replace URL to freindly URL like **(test-test-test-test)**

in english everything works fine but in arabic not work **(مرحبا-مرحبا-مرحبا-مرحبا)** **not working** probably

```
// English function work fine! replace long title with dashes 
// ex: hello-world-how-is-everything
    function seoUrl($string) {
        $string = strtolower($string);
        $string = str_replace('&',' ',$string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
        return $string;
    }
```

so i want it to be work in arabic language..
thanks

Comment: You should at the UTF8 modifier at the end of your expression so `preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/u", "", $string);` for example. But what do you expect here because this wont replace anything obvioulsy.

Comment: Perhaps you want the unicode letter property `"\P{L}"` which will replace any unicode character letter. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php for further reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your code in several places, mainly, by matching any Unicode letters/digits and replacing multiple consecutive hyphens or whitespaces with a single one. Also, your replacements need to be adjusted, too:

```php
function seoUrl($string) {
        $string = mb_strtolower($string);
        $string = str_replace('&',' ',$string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[^\w\s-]+/u", " ", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/u", " ", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]+/u", "-", $string);
        return $string;
    }

echo seoUrl("Test--++_-__-Test----Test$#%#Test") . PHP_EOL;
echo seoUrl("مرحبا--++_-__مرحباt--مرحباst$#%#مرحبا") . PHP_EOL;
// => test-test-test-test
// => مرحبا-مرحباt-مرحباst-مرحبا
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/8tcop).

Notes:

- `mb_strtolower($string);` - to deal with Unicode strings, `mb_strtolower` is preferred
- `preg_replace("/[^\w\s-]+/u", " ", $string)` - with the `/u` flag, `\w` and `\s` match any Unicode word and whitespace chars, so you no longer remove Arabic and other letters/digits; mind you need to replace matches with a space, not an empty string here
- `preg_replace("/[\s-]+/u", " ", $string)` and `preg_replace("/[\s_]+/u", "-", $string)` - `u` flag is added, `+` ensures whole consecutive match chunks are replaced, not chars one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function seoUrl($string) {
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = str_replace('&',' ',$string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[chr(0600)-chr(0600FF)a-z0-9_\s-]/is", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
var_dump(seoUrl("مرحبا-مرحبا-مرحبا-مرحبا"));
```

I don't know if this is what you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your time first, secound thats not what im looking for, i want if user type in subject name in arabic letter like (مرحبا اهلاً بكم) function replace the spaces with (مرحبا-اهلاً-بكم) that's what i'm looking for.